How to maintain Authentication State with Blazor 8 Server Interactive
I have a setup a full example project here with a kludge where I have to manually call it to grab the state on every page.  The problem is if the user refreshes the page then it will redirect to login because the Authorize will hit before the OnAfterRenderAsync
https://github.com/GregFinzer/Blazor8Auth
I want to use what is built into Blazor 8 but I am not able to figure out the correct configuration.  Here is what I have in my program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

//Authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "auth_token";
        options.LoginPath = "/login";
        options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/acessDenied";
    });

builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();

builder.Services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICustomSessionService, CustomSessionService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();

Here is my AuthService that I am calling on every page
﻿using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace Blazor8Auth.Services
{
    public class AuthService
    {
        const string AuthTokenName = "auth_token";
        public event Action<ClaimsPrincipal>? UserChanged;
        private ClaimsPrincipal? currentUser;
        private readonly ICustomSessionService _sessionService;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public AuthService(ICustomSessionService sessionService, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _sessionService = sessionService;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public ClaimsPrincipal CurrentUser
        {
            get { return currentUser ?? new(); }
            set
            {
                currentUser = value;

                if (UserChanged is not null)
                {
                    UserChanged(currentUser);
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsLoggedIn => CurrentUser.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false;

        public async Task LogoutAsync()
        {
            CurrentUser = new();
            string authToken = await _sessionService.GetItemAsStringAsync(AuthTokenName);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authToken))
            {
                await _sessionService.RemoveItemAsync(AuthTokenName);
            }
        }

        public async Task GetStateFromTokenAsync()
        {
            string authToken = await _sessionService.GetItemAsStringAsync(AuthTokenName);

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authToken))
            {
                try
                {
                    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                    var key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value);

                    tokenHandler.ValidateToken(authToken, new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                    }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

                    var jwtToken = (JwtSecurityToken)validatedToken;
                    identity = new ClaimsIdentity(jwtToken.Claims, "jwt");
                }
                catch
                {
                    await _sessionService.RemoveItemAsync(AuthTokenName);
                    identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
                }
            }

            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            CurrentUser = user;
        }


        public async Task Login(ClaimsPrincipal user)
        {
            CurrentUser = user;

            var tokenEncryptionKey = _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value;
            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                .GetBytes(tokenEncryptionKey));
            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);
            var tokenHoursString = _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:TokenHours").Value;
            int.TryParse(tokenHoursString, out int tokenHours);
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                claims: user.Claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(tokenHours),
                signingCredentials: creds);

            var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            await _sessionService.SetItemAsStringAsync(AuthTokenName, jwt);
        }
    }
}

Here is the code that has to be on every page:
@code {
    [Inject] private AuthService AuthService { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (!AuthService.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            await AuthService.GetStateFromTokenAsync();
        }
    }
}


The reason for this issue is missing SignInAsync method. It cause the users not keep log in status.
And Blazor Don't Completely access To httpContext, so you need to make login page with Razor Or MVC Page.
For more details, you can check this to make a razor page in my your project.

Thanks for this answer Jason.  Now I have the problem that I don't know what to put in the program.cs to be able to have a login.cshtml razor page in my Blazor project.  I am getting a 404 not found when navigating to login

Hi @GregFinzer Please update your repo with the latest issue when you are free, thanks~

I have pushed to the git repo.  Thanks.

@GregFinzer Try to use builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options => {     options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute()); }).WithRazorPagesRoot("/Components/Pages"); in your Program.cs and return Redirect("/"); in Login - OnPostAsync

But I still facing InvalidOperationException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. issue, this seems to be a shortcoming of the Blazor project, so your authentication logic for your current scenario is really bad. It is recommended to read the official documentation.

Jason, I am still getting a 404 after adding this line:  builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options => {     options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute()); }).WithRazorPagesRoot("/Components/Pages");  I did read through that official documentation.  I have been stuck on this for over a week.  Unfortunately there are no examples of logging in or logging out for Server Interactive render mode unless you use the individual accounts project template.

@GregFinzer Sorry，I forget to mention builder.Services.AddRazorPages andapp.MapRazorPages();

I added that.  I am able to get to the login page and submit.  The problem is that the HTTPContext is null which is the same problem as a Razor Component with a page directive.

@GregFinzer We can use httpcontextaccessor to implement this, as I said yesterday, finally we will  face InvalidOperationException issue, it's a limitation in Blazor.

I finally figured out what I would call an interim solution where the state is maintained both on the Browser Session and the Blazor Back End.  I don't have to put auth code on every page now.  See the giant readme.md  https://github.com/GregFinzer/Blazor8Auth
